# How to manually uninstall a Visual Studio 2010 extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

So I got prompted to download the latest NuGet Package Manager in VS2010.
All previous updates (including this) has failed with:
`VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The installed version of 'NuGet Package Manager' is signed, but the update version has an invalid signature. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.`

Which, in itself has been going on for some time now, and [they still haven't fixed it (look in Q&A)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/).

Ok, fine, previously I could simply uninstall the NuGet extension and install the latest. However, this time, both the `Disable` and `Uninstall` buttons are disabled.
So I can't uninstall and I can't upgrade.

Catch22.

How can I manually remove the NuGet extension from Visual Studio?
What files/folders/reg entries do I have to kill to get rid of NuGet?

Comment: It seems that someone is on a "off-topic" close voting killing spree. May I  quote from the Official SO FAQ: **"...but if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers then you’re in the right place to ask your question! "**

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To uninstall NuGet, you must first run Visual Studio as Administrator, then you will see the Uninstall option available.

Restart VS, but this time run it as your normal account. When you install NuGet going forward, you should be able to update to future versions without running as Administrator.

I believe this issue occurs due to NuGet being installed with MVC 3. I hope in the future we no longer bundle NuGet with other software.

Comment: to be 100% explicity clear, having Administrator privileges on your user account does not make this work, you should right-click on VS2010 on the menu and click 'Run As Administrator' - I hope this saves someone else a few hours of messing around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is fixed now. There is a very new release.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues#Upgrading_to_latest_NuGet_from_an_older_version_causes_a_signature_verification_error.
When viewing the logs, you might see a mention of a SignatureMismatchException.
To prevent this from occurring, there is a Visual Studio 2010 SP1 hotfix you can install. Alternatively, the workaround is to simply uninstall NuGet and then install it from the VS Extension Gallery. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581019 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete/uninstall Nuget package which is applied to **multiple projects in your solutions** then go to:

1. Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution
2. In the left column where is 'Installed packages' select 'All', so you'll
   see a list of installed packages and Manage button across them.
3. Select Manage button and you'll get a pop out, deselect the checkbox across project name and Ok it

The rest of the work Package Manager will do it for you.

Comment: This explains how to uninstall a NuGet package. The question is asking how to uninstall the NuGet extension from Visual Studio.