# Visual Studio 2010 - Uninstall NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget

How do you uninstall NuGet from Visual Studio 2010?

I tried to open Visual Studio 2010 with 'Run as Administrator', but the Uninstall option is not available for uninstalling the NuGet extension from VS2010.

Comment: Did you try as per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646936/how-to-manually-uninstall-a-visual-studio-2010-extension

Answer (score 55):

Usually to uninstall NuGet in VS2010 you need to run as an administrator, open Tools->Extension Manager. In Installed, select NuGet and click Uninstall.

If that fails you can run this command :

vsixinstaller.exe /uninstall:NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5

(vsixinstaller can be found under [program files]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE )

Comment: Running as an administrator helps. It's really weird.

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me as well and I am using VS 2015

Answer (score 6):

Open Extension Manager inside Visual Studio, select "Installed" on the left, you'll find NuGet in the list and the option to remove it.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but it looks like that is exactly what the OP has already tried, just that there is no `Uninstall` button/option available. From the question one can also "assume" that he did run VS as administrator while trying, like suggested [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1317).

Comment: He does not say about Extension Manager. I got, that he was trying to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall NuGet, you must first run Visual Studio as Administrator, then you will see the Uninstall option available.

Restart VS, but this time run it as your normal account. When you install NuGet going forward, you should be able to update to future versions without running as Administrator.

I believe this issue occurs due to NuGet being installed with MVC 3. I hope in the future we no longer bundle NuGet with other software.